# Using CacheBuilder and redis together

Tags: java, redis, guava

Guava `CacheBuilder` only uses a single JVM. I want to use the `CacheBuilder` interface to load data from `redis` and `redis` in turn loads the data from `MySQL`.

How do I solve it? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try Spring Cache framework?It did good wrapper around Redis.